# (From Awodey)$\sf C \cong D$ be equivalent categories then $\sf C$ has binary products if and only if $\sf D$ does.

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation

This is Awodey exercise 7.12. I have difficulty understanding why the middle arrow is indeed unique.

Solution says that it is unique by the uniqueness of $h$, but I am stuck on how to deduce the uniqueness of the middle map is deduced from the uniqueness of $h$. Some more details or useful relative fact or lemmas, please? Thanks!

The solution:

If $\sf C\cong D$, then there are functors $F :{\sf C \rightleftarrows D} : G$ and natural isomorphisms $α :1_{\sf D} → FG$ and $β : GF →1_{\sf C}$. Suppose $\sf C$ has products, and let $D,D' ∈\sf D$ be given. We claim that $F(GD × GD')$ is a product object of $D$ and $D'$, with projections $α^{−1}_{\sf D} ◦ Fπ_1^{GD×GD'}$ and $α^{−1}_{\sf D} ◦ Fπ_2^{GD×GD'}$ . For suppose we have an object $Z$ and arrows $a : Z → D$ and $a' : Z → D'$ in $\sf D$. There is a unique $h : GZ → GD ×GD' ∈\sf C$ such that $π^{GD×GD'}_1 ◦h = Ga$ and $π^{GD×GD'}_2 ◦ h = Ga'$. Then the mediating map in $\sf D$ is $Fh◦ α_Z$. We can calculate $α^{−1}_D ◦Fπ^{GD×GD'}_1 ◦Fh◦α_Z = α^{−1}_D ◦F(π^{GD×GD'}_1 h)◦α_Z = α^{−1}_D ◦FGa◦α_Z = α^{−1}_D ◦α_D ◦a = a$ and similarly for the second projection. Uniqueness of the map $Fh◦α_Z$ follows from that of $h$.

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189)
of your post. Pictures may not be legible,
cannot be searched and are not view-able to some,
such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: If there were another such map, necessarily of the form $k\circ \alpha_Z$ for some $k$, then by fullness of $F$, there is some $l$ with $F(l) = k$. Then by going back up the equalities, you get that $l$ satisfies the same condition as $h$ (there you will use the faithfulness of $F$)

Comment: @GNUSupporter I have edited and typed the solution in MathJax.

Comment: @Max Thanks! Sorry it is still unclear to me that why the arrow is necessarily of the form $k\circ \alpha_Z$. Could you please explain?

Comment: @Max I see. Since $\alpha$ is an isomorphism, for any arrow $f:Z\to F(GD\times GD')$, I can construct the arrow $k:FG(Z)\to F(GD\times GD')$ as $\alpha^{-1}_Z\circ f$. So I have $f=k\circ \alpha_Z$. This solves my problem.